# Mysql query based on unknown number of parameters

Tags: php, mysql

Users select some parameters with checkboxes from an **HTML form**:

Example: they choose eggs, carrots and beans from 100 possible ingredients.

These selected parameters are stored in an array such as **$ingredients['eggs','carrots','beans'];**

A **mysql query** has to input name results where eggs=1, carrots=1, and beans=1

```
    $db->query("SELECT name, FROM ingredients WHERE eggs=1, carrots=1, beans=1")->fetchall();
```

But how if I have **$ingredients** has a different size?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: generate string for where condition through foreach loop and concat with query.

Comment: You haven't given us much to go on. What is your database structure?

Comment: he just want a where part of the query like he asked?? why do you need database stucture???? @Kuya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$where = "WHERE 1 ";
foreach($ingredients as $key=>$value){
    $where.=" AND {$value}=1";
}
```